# Realistic Vanilla TNT Run

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building self regenerating mini games for Minecraft and I had an idea for tnt run. Originally I just had pressure plates activating TNT, but I had an idea that would make it look like the Spleef on cube craft. I started off by making a repeating command block (always active) with the following command:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ stone
```

I hooked this up to a chain command block (conditional, always active)

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /setblock  ~ ~-1 air
```

However, I found that it removed the block too quickly, so I put a comparator in the middle, but the same thing happened except the blocks were deleted slower yet still directly beneath the Player. I tried hooking it up to a clock and replacing the test for block command block every time it found stone, but I don't know the block NBT data for always active. All that I can think of other than hooking up different kind of clocks.

Comment: Did you try repeaters between the comparator and the second command block? If you play with the tick delay, you might get what you're looking for. And avoid the complicated scoreboard while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

type this into chat:

```
/scoreboard objectives add time50 dummy
```

Then put the following into unconditional command blocks:

```
/scoreboard players add @a time50 1

execute @a[score_time50_min=5] ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ stone
```

This one goes in a conditional command block:

```
execute @a[score_time50_min=5] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
```

This one in an unconditional:

```
/scoreboard players reset @a[score_time50_min=5] time50
```

Comment: So these should all be connected as chain blocks?

Comment: It helps but the player will still fall through after about 5 bloccks worth of running. Should i try changing the min=5 to min=4 or something like that? I have basic knowledge of scoreboard objectives.

Comment: the min=5 stands for how many game ticks run by. if you change it to 20 it will will remove a block every 1 second because 20 ticks is = to 1 second, 10 = half a second, 5 = quarter second. You can change the number to anything.

Comment: Also, if this helped please click the check mark, if not then please tell me why.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. This simply removes the blocks at a slower rate not remove the block that your standing on right now to be deleted in 3 quarters of a second. Also the way that you explained on how to set it up is not clear. Is the first supposed to be a repeating command block? Is it supposed to be wired as chain blocks or by using a comparator between each block?